# encode URL so it can be send through GET

Tags: javascript, url, uri

What is the best way to attach URL to query string in javascript? I realize that it needs to be encoded.

I've come across `encodeURIComponent()` function, which looks like the thing that I want. I am just unsure if it is suitable for this kind of task.

Example usage:

```
var someURL = encodeURIComponent("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?name=.hil#");

var firstURL = "www.stackoverflow.com/questions?someurl="

firstURL+someURL;
```

Comment: Yes encodeURIComponent will provide the correct encoding.

Comment: encodeURIComponent is the right function for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your choices are `encodeURI` and `encodeURIComponent`.
`encodeURIComponent` is the right choice because you are encoding part of the URL (which happens to be URL-like but that doesn't matter here).
If you were to use `encodeURI`, it would not convert enough of the characters in the component.